# Jquery Regex - check one or multiple comma separated values (12 hex characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui

I currently have a textbox that can take one or multiple (comma separated) values.

`var textBox = $('#testValues').val().split(",");`

I'm trying to add regex validation that when users enter one or multiple values (always has to be 12 hex characters) and hit submit, then the regex checks and makes an API call if it passes else throws an alert message.

I currently have like this. 
`var regexValidation = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,12}$");`

`if (regexValidation.test(textBox)) { apiCall }` 
`else { alert('Regex validation failed'); return false;}`

It works great when I ONLY entered 1 value. However, if I try to enter multiple values with "," then it just throws an alert message. I do not want to add a comma in the regex because then it will take 12 hex characters including a comma. How should I handle it?

Thank you.

Comment: If it has to be 12 characters, then you might have another issue since you currently also allow 0-11 characters per value. Either way, I'd say an extra optional group at the end will do. Answer given by @Toto =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add multiple optional values:

```
var regexValidation = new RegExp("^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}(?:\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{12})*\s*$");
```

Comment: I changed it to new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(?:,[0-9a-fA-F]{12})*$"); so it always takes 12 hex characters. However, it does not ignore white spaces. How can I make it to ignore the white spaces? I put \s right after the [0-9a-fA-F]\s like this but it doesn't work

Comment: @davis: What do you mean with “it does not ignore white spaces”? Could you give an example of value that must be matched?

Comment: Sure, let's say there are 1 value in the textbox. 

ABCDEABCDE12. If there's a whitespace anywhere in the text, this regex doesn't work.

Comment: Samething for when I enter multiple values.

ABCDEABCDE12, "           "       ABCDEABCDE13 a white space this in between the values after comma won't work.(sorry adding "   "  to show you there's a white space.)

Comment: @davis: If the space is just before or after the hexa values: `new RegExp("^\s*[a-f0-9]{12}\s*(?:,\s*[a-f0-9]{12}\s*)*$", "i");`. If the space can be anywhere in the hexa values,, it's a little bit more complex: `new RegExp("^(?:\s*[a-f0-9]){12}\s*(?:,(?:\s*[a-f0-9]){12}\s*)*$", "i");`. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: @davis: May be you have to double escape `\\s` or define the regex like that: `var regexValidation = /^\s*[a-f0-9]{12}\s*(?:,\s*[a-f0-9]{12}\s*)*$/i;` or `var regexValidation = /^(?:\s*[a-f0-9]){12}\s*(?:,(?:\s*[a-f0-9]){12}\s*)*$/i;`

Comment: @davis: Sorry, I don't get you; I guess you've missed the `$` anchor at the end of regex. `/^[a-f0-9}{12}$/i` or `new RegExp('^[a-f0-9]{12}$', 'i');` for one value.

Comment: Sorry, I got that work. You are correct, I forgot to add *$ at the end.
Here's a tricky part. It is good for when I enter 1 value. However, if there are multiple (there's a feature that I currently have is that import a lot of data from database and it just populates all into the textbox), there are just so many white spaces before and after the commas and the regex just doesn't work at that point

Comment: And if I just use new RegExp("^([0-9a-fA-F]{12}(?:,[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}))*$");
even 1 value (12 hex characters) doesn't work

Comment: new RegExp('^[a-f0-9]{12}$', 'i');
This is great for one value. Is there way to make it like one or more (comma seperate) and ignore any white spaces before or after a comma? I've been trying those above ones and others but nothing's working ;(

Comment: If it's for only one value, then its perfect. But as I need to 1 or more.. it gets werid.

Comment: @davis: see my edit, add some optional spaces `\s*`

Comment: It still works great when there's only 1 value, but if there are more than 1, for example, 00032D14A6DA ,00032D158E7E or like 00032D14A6DA ,             " just showing you there are a lot of whitespaces"           
  00032D158E7E, then the regex will not be working :(

Comment: Thanks Toto, I really appreciate your help! I just decided to remove any whitespaces .replace(/\s/gm, ''); before the regex validations. They way I don't have to worry about my regex going crazy. haha. So It's working great with your regex now.